# Reference request - Problem book by subject

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, problem-solving

I'm looking for good problem textbooks for self-study. 
I know only of two of this sort: "Introduction to Measure Theory" by Terry Tao, and "Problems in Algebraic Number Theory" by Esmonde and Murty.

Perhaps Spivak, Calculus on Manifolds enters the list as well.

I would like to know if you know any more textbooks on subjects such as Topology, Algebra, Geometry,etc who share this "left for the reader as an exercise" philosophy or that introduce new results almost only via exercises.

Comment: For topology, there's the book by Viro.